# Наименовать - именовать; две природы Христа, или Как выйти из положения (→)?

Tags: выбор-слов, прописная-строчная, точное-словоупотребление

> Ведь наименование Иисус Христос относится к Богочеловеку.

В контексте:

> Итак, иконоборческому мышлению представлялось, что иконой может быть
>   только предмет, тождественный изображаемому. Если же тождества нет, то
>   и образа быть не может. Следовательно, **изображение**, сделанное
>   художником, **не может быть иконой Христовой**. Вообще изобразительное
>   искусство — богохульство в отношении догмата Боговоплощения. Что же
>   делает невежественный художник, когда дает форму тому, во что можно
>   только верить сердцем и исповедовать устами? — спрашивают иконоборцы.
>   Ведь **наименование Иисус Христос** относится к Богочеловеку. Значит,
>   изображая Его, вы богохульствуете вдвойне: во-первых, вы пытаетесь
>   изобразить **Божество, Которое неизобразимо**; во-вторых, если вы
>   пытаетесь изобразить на иконе и Божественную, и человеческую **природы
>   Христа**, то этим вы стремитесь к слиянию этих природ, а это есть
>   монофизитство.

Шрифтом выделено то, что меня смущает.

---

Я сейчас встретила: двуединая природа, а не дикие мне две природы.

Comment: Мне кажется, всё в порядке. Природа и двуедина и можно рассмотреть как две отдельных. Никакого нет противоречия, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Да, "наименование" плохо, лучше "имя".

Comment: Уважаемая Галина, так Вы всё еще работаете? лексика Ваших недавних вопросов какая то не пенсионерская.

Comment: Это не работа, то есть не заработок. Именно развлечение. Ну и конечно, помощь давней знакомой, которая не раз меня выручала. Мы не виделись и не слышались с 2007 года.